# Activating a registered account using code (PHP + JS)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently working on a project and managed to get  a working registration and login form. Upon registration, the user is emailed with a 5 character activation code and is asked to insert it on the user profile page in order to change the status from active:0 to active:1 and gains permission to the rest of the site.

For some reason the activation code just simply won't work :/

The following code is the PHP code written to activate the account, I am using PDO queries to connect to the database, but I tried using a mysqli query too but didn't seem to work.

```
<?php
session_start();

    // Allow the config
        define('__CONFIG__', true);
    // Require the config
    require_once "inc/config.php";  //possibly have to change the location
    include_once "inc/classes/DB.php"; //possibly have to change location
    include_once "inc/classes/Page.php";
    include_once "inc/classes/User.php";

    Page::ForceLogin();
//
//$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST['email'] );
//$username = Filter::String($_POST['username']);
//$skills = Filter::String($_POST['skills']);
//$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST['email'] );
//$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST['username'] );

    $return=[];

$User = new User($_SESSION['user_id']);
$username = $User->username;


////Connection Variables
//$host = 'localhost';
//$user = 'root';
//$password = '';
//$db = 'mdb_';
////Creating mysql connection
//$conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db);




//$username = $User->username;


$activationCode = User::Find(INPUT_GET['activationCode']);

if(isset($_GET['activationCode'])) {
    if(!empty($_GET['activationCode'])) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='.$username.'";
        $result = query($con, $query);
        if(ocirowcount($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                if($_GET['activationCode'] == $row["activationCode"]){
                    $con->query ("UPDATE users SET active=1 AND credit=100 WHERE username = '.$username.'");
                    $return['error'] = 'Your account is now activated! You have earned 100 Time-banking credits.';
                    //header("Refresh:0");
                }
                else{
                    $return['error'] = 'Code incorrect, please try again';
                }
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}

//$activationCode = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "activationCode" );
//if(isset($_GET['activationCode'])) {
//    if(!empty($_GET['activationCode'])) {
//        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
//        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
//        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
//            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
//                if($_GET['activationCode'] == $row["activationCode"]){
//                    $sql = $conn->query ("UPDATE users SET active=1 AND credit=100 WHERE username = '$username'");
//                    $return['error'] = 'Your account is now activated! You have earned 100 Time-banking credits.';
//                    //header("Refresh:0");
//                }
//                else{
//                    $return['error'] = 'Code incorrect, please try again';
//                }
//            }
//        }
//        echo json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
//    }
//}

//$activationCode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "activationCode" );
//
//  if(isset($_POST['activationCode'])) {
//      $activationCode = Filter::String( $_POST['activationCode'] );
//
//
//
//
//
//      $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
//          $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
//          if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
//
//              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
//
//                  if($_POST['activationCode'] == $row["activationCode"]){
//
//
//                      $activateUser = $con->query ("UPDATE `users` SET  `credit` = :100, `active` = :1, WHERE `user_id` = :$user_id");
//                      //$sql = $con->query ("UPDATE users SET active=1, credit=100 WHERE username = '$username'");
//
//                      $return['error'] = 'Your account is now activated! You have earned 100 Time-banking credits.';
//
//                      header("Refresh:0");
//                  }
//                  else{
//                      $return['error'] = 'Code incorrect, please try again';
//                  }
//
//              }
//          }
//
//      echo json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
//
////      }
//  }



?>
```

The code below is the db class that creates the $con in PDO

```
class DB {

    protected static $con;

    private function __construct(){
        try {

            self::$con = new PDO( 'mysql:charset=latin1;host=host;port=****;dbname=mdb_', 'root', 'pass'); //change connection string
            self::$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            self::$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
            self::$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, false );
            self::$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Could not connect todatabase."; exit;
        }
    }


    public static function getConnection() {
        //If this instance has not been started, start it.
        if (!self::$con) {
            new DB();
        }
        //Return the writeable db connection
        return self::$con;
    }
```

Comment: The update syntax is not ok. Try with UPDATE users SET active=1, credit=100 ...

Comment: There is more wrong than that. You say you're using PDO, but I see a `mysqli_fetch_array` in there. Also, the string concatenation for entering `$username` into both the SELECT and UPDATE queries is wrong. You're using double quotes to delimit your strings, that means the variable will be interpreted and you shouldn't use the `.` at all. But you should **really** use prepared statements so you don't risk SQL injection if a user tries to register a username with a `'` in it (or, `' OR '1'='1`, which would activate all accounts if the other issues are fixed and they enter a valid code).

Comment: Also just noticed the `ocirowcount()` in there, which has been deprecated since PHP 5.4 and only works with OCI8 Oracle database connections, not with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: @rickdenhaan what would the equivalent for them be for PDO? I'm really new with pdo and still trying to learn to adjust. I'm unsure if the changes i'd need to make?

Comment: PDO uses an object-oriented interface. Looking at the way you execute the SELECT using `query($con, $query)`, I strongly suspect that you're *actually* using mysqli and not PDO. Is that correct? Where does `$con` come from?

Comment: @rickdenhaan I edited the question to include the db class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here, from mixing database API's to possible SQL injection, string concatenation issues and incorrect SQL syntax in your UPDATE query.

If you're using PDO for your database connection, you need to remove all references to the `oci*` (which are for Oracle databases) and `mysqli*` (which is a different API and not compatible with PDO) functions, and use the PDO equivalents.

I will also remove `$username` from the queries and use prepared statements instead. `$username` may be coming from your own database, but I can't see how it got in there. If you do not have a limit on which characters a username can contain, and the username is properly escaped when it is inserted into your database, then it may contain single (or double) quotes that can still cause trouble in this code. Bottom line: if it was originally user input, it should never be trusted.

```
// I missed this in the code in your question
$con = DB::getConnection();

if (isset($_GET['activationCode'])) {
    if(!empty($_GET['activationCode'])) {
        // Note the placeholder ":username" -- PDO will fill that with
        // $username for you (see $stmt->execute() below) and take care
        // of adding quotes around it
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";

        try {
            $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));

            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                foreach ($stmt as $row) {
                    if ($_GET['activationCode'] == $row["activationCode"]) {
                        // note the syntax: "SET active=1, credit=100"
                        $update = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET active=1, credit=100 WHERE username = :username");
                        $update->execute(array(':username' => $username));

                        $return['error'] = 'Your account is now activated! You have earned 100 Time-banking credits.';
                        //header("Refresh:0");
                    } else {
                        $return['error'] = 'Code incorrect, please try again';
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (PDOException $error) {
            $return['error'] = (string)$error;
        }

        echo json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}
```

Note that this can be somewhat optimised by just attempting the UPDATE query. For the sake of convenience, I'll also assume you only want the activation code to be able to be used on inactive accounts, which you aren't currently checking:

```
$con = DB::getConnection();

if (isset($_GET['activationCode']) && !empty($_GET['activationCode'])) {
    $query = "UPDATE users SET active = 1, credit = 100 WHERE username = :username AND activationCode = :code AND active = 0";

    try {
        $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':username' => $username,
            ':code' => $_GET['activationCode']
        ));

        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $return['error'] = 'Your account is now activated! You have earned 100 Time-banking credits.';
        } else {
            $return['error'] = 'Code incorrect or account is already active, please try again';
        }
    } catch (PDOException $error) {
        $return['error'] = (string)$error;
    }

    echo json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

Comment: There seems to be an error for this

"$return['error'] = (string)$error;

Comment: Yes, I saw. I've updated the answer, are you still getting an error (and if so, what is the error)?

Comment: That works now! but it's displaying the $error message at the top of the page rather than the alert that I've set for it                                                                       " <center><div class="uk-margin uk-alert-danger js-error" style='display: none;'></div></center>"

for the registration and login pages, the errors are displayed through that,but it is linked to a JS page,

Comment: That's a different issue, depends on the rest of your code. It could be as simple as moving that `echo json_encode($return)` somewhere else. If you're actually calling this page from another page using AJAX, the problem could be there. I suggest opening a new question for that with the relevant code.

Comment: yeah I might do, thanks a lot for helping with the main question then :D it's all done now